# Information about network interface in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

How can I get information about let's say `eth0` in kernel space? I need to know if it's enabled or disabled, if it has set ipv6 (and ipv6 of course).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [struct net_device](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1532):

```
#include <linux/netdevice.h>

struct net_device *net_dev = __dev_get_by_name("eth0");

net_dev->flags; // IFF_UP will be set if an interface active (up)
```

To obtain IPv6 address, you need to get [struct inet6_dev](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/if_inet6.h?v=3.2#L162) out of your net_device, and get IP address from it:

```
#include <net/addrconf.h>
#include <net/if_inet6.h>

struct inet6_dev *net_dev6 = in6_dev_get(net_device);
```

Comment: Thank You, it is working solution. However I still can not figure out how to get ipv6 address. I tried something like that:

    void get_ipv6(char * buf){
        struct net_device *dev;
        dev = _dev_get_by_name("eth0");

        sprintf(buf, "%pI6", dev->ip6_ptr->something); //i do not know exact field
    }
When I want to get something from ip6_ptr i always get "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Comment: @Kalvy I have edited my answer; I would appreciate if you've marked it as correct if it is the case. Thanks.

Comment: Can You tell me exactly where the ip6v address is?

Answer (score 0):

If you get trouble getting ipv6 address from a `inet6_dev` instance,you could get some clue in the kernel source code

(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv6/addrconf.c)

```
static void ipv6_link_dev_addr(struct inet6_dev *idev, struct inet6_ifaddr *ifp) {
    struct list_head *p;
    int ifp_scope = ipv6_addr_src_scope(&ifp->addr);

    /*
     * Each device address list is sorted in order of scope -
     * global before linklocal.
     */
    list_for_each(p, &idev->addr_list) {
        struct inet6_ifaddr *ifa
            = list_entry(p, struct inet6_ifaddr, if_list);
        if (ifp_scope >= ipv6_addr_src_scope(&ifa->addr))
            break;
    }

    list_add_tail_rcu(&ifp->if_list, p);
}
```

From the code above it's clear that `addr_list` field of `inet6_dev` could be used to get ipv6 address by invoking `list_entry()` on `inet6_dev::addr_list.next`. The addr_list.next field is  actually embedded in a `inet6_ifaddr` struct.